# ASP.NET MVC5 not saving to the database

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'd like to get a user from db by ID field, update one of the fields and save it.

I have a following action in my Users controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        AspNetUser mister = db.AspNetUsers.Find(12);
        mister.Permissions = 2;
        db.Entry(mister).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index", "users");
    }
```

It is finding a right user, modifies the value on the mister object and calls save. Doesn't give any errors, but it is not saving?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably localdb, looking at the wrong file. Happens all the time.

Comment: get the number of entities saved by checking the return value of SaveChanges method like this : var saved = db.SaveChanges();